# Core Data Performance with Single Parent Entity

Tags: sql, objective-c, database, sqlite, core-data

I am creating a framework that works with Core Data. One of the requirements for using my framework on your Core Data class is that any entity you want to have the Framework's capabilities will need to be sub entities and sub classes of an entity I provide to you. For the sake of this I will call that object Foo.

Today I realized that Core Data stores all objects that are sub entities of Foo into a table called ZFOO. I'm worried about the performance of Core Data if someone with massive data sets wants to use it, since ALL sub entities of the foo class will be store in one enormous ZFOO table.

Any opinions or recommendations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, subclasses is generally bad in CoreData if you have large data sets since you could end up with very parse tables. However, my recommendation is to test first... Write a simple application that creates thousands of objects of many different subclasses of your class Foo and see how the system behaves. If it's not noticeable then maybe you'r fine anyway. Always test before you make assumptions about speed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was more looking for horror stories of this going very wrong. The more I read the more Apple seems to actually encourage this kind of inheritance in Core Data.

Comment: I can confirm that it still does this in Xcode 5 DP5.

Comment: I confirm that Core Data still does it in Xcode 7 iOS 9.2, cannot believe it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Last year I worked on a project that did the same thing, we stored everything in core data and everything in core data inherited from a single class which had some common attributes.

We had somewhere between 1k - 10k records in core data and performance degraded to the point where we rewrote it and removed the common ancestor.  As I recall simple searches were taking multiple seconds, and insertions / updates were pretty crappy too.  It was only after things had gotten painfully slow that we cracked the db open and noticed under the covers core data was storing everything in one table.

Sorry I don't remember specific numbers, the big takeaway was we had to redo it because it was too slow, and not too slow like too slow for high frequency trading but too slow like the app crashed on load when trying to populate the initial view out of core data.

So, with the grain of salt that this was on older iOS and older hardware, I would say definitely do not do this.

Comment: Apple recommends, in one of their advanced Core Data videos, not to subclass entities in Core Data.

Comment: +1 Thanks Deathbob and @Christopher Bradford - you both saved me a lot of trouble after I detected this was happening in the early stages of developing an app!

Comment: VERY annoying problem. I made a subclass of a managed object and expected to be able to put them in separate tables. Totally ruins the table views when they're fetched together! There's really no way to separate them?

Comment: Is this still valid in year 2020?

Answer (score 37):

I worked with @deathbob on this project as the iOS lead. In our instance I had multiple classes which contained the attributes "remote_id" and "remote_update". I initially set the tables up using subclasses. I had a "RemoteEntity" abstract entity which contained those attributes and a bunch of other entities which inherited from it, each with their own. I *thought* that we would end up with a bunch of tables each with remote_id, remote_update, and then their custom attributes. Instead we ended up with the massive table you describe.

The fix was pretty simple you **must** not set up inheritance through the GUI. Instead include all attributes for that object including your shared ones in the Core Data modeller (this means "remote_id" and "remote_update" will appear in each entity. That being said we can still use a subclass. After generating your models' classes, create the parent entity's class. This must **not** be in the GUI. It should inherit from NSManagedObject and in the .m file the properties should use @dynamic instead of @synthesize. Now that you have the parent class it is time to adjust the child classes. Set the parent class to RemoteEntity (in my example) instead of NSManagedObject. Then remove any properties that appear in your super class (in my example, "remote_id" and "remote_update").

Here is an example of my super class https://gist.github.com/1121689.

I hope this helps, hat tip to @deathbob for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm having the same problem (single parent entity, terrible performance) and was wondering if an approach like the one you describe would work. How do you deal with relationships to the parent entity?

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect! This way you have one interface in code, and many tables in BD (as it should be)

Comment: This sounds like a work around of something which should also be done threw the gui. So may it was a bug back than!? Do you still do it that way or did something change since than?

Comment: I tried this today, but how do you guys execute a fetch on the "RemoteEntity" Entity?

Comment: This won't work in my specific case, but I'm glad to hear it works for some. Sounds like a weird bug.

Comment: How did you handle inverse relationships that contained a common sub-class?

Comment: I'm also curious about how do you handle relationships to the parent entity

Comment: I am having the same issue and no success implementing the above method. I have been try all permutations and combinations to make this work, but could not. I get error like cannot change mutable object, improper key path, blank super entity. I have studied all the apple documentation fr this but somehow I am missing something in implementation. Can someone pls help me with a template code or reference. Thanking in advance

Answer (score 4):

Hindsight is a wonderful thing.

As people are still reading this Q&A and referring to it in their questions and thinking that nothing has changed, I'd like to add a few comments for clarity and to provide a "modern" or more recent response.

Core data is a powerful beast, but you must learn to control the beast, and thanks to the pioneers who have answered previously and the improvements that Apple has made to the framework, it is a lot easier to do today than it was a couple of years ago (in particular iOS 5).

Initially I'd recommend learning how to prepare a solid and robust data model. There is a huge amount of information on this so I will leave it to the reader to investigate. As the previous answers mention, it is important to learn to prepare all relationships in the data model.

Beyond that, there are a number of mechanisms to control the size of data set you fetch. It has not been better explained to me than in a book from The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013) by Marcus S. Zarra, and in particular Chapter 4 titled "Performance Tuning”.

Read it.