# Using Parent Entity in CoreData Models

Tags: cocoa, sqlite, core-data, entity

I started using entity inheritance today with core data, does anyone have any experience with this feature?. I see that all of my entities that have a parent entity have now converted into one big table when opening the sqlite file. I'm worried about performance and table locks. Anyone please share their experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Reverend,

While your schema can dramatically affect your performance, added columns to rows in a table is not your performance problem. Traversing complex relations and managing large BLOBs is your performance problem.

Yes, I use the entity inheritance. Yes, it is fast. Yes, it has allowed me to make a sane model. That said, the conventional OOP wisdom these days is to limit the depth of your inheritance hierarchies. This is probably a good idea when using Core Data. Composition of objects/entities is your friend.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Your concerns are warranted. Depending on the number of entities and fields, the performance might degrade noticeably when you have more than a few thousand managed objects.

Others had this problem, too: [Core Data Performance with Single Parent Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917494/core-data-performance-with-single-parent-entity)