# Simperium tried to send object changes for nil key

Tags: simperium

What does `Simperium tried to send object changes for nil key` mean and how can I debug / fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This will occur if an object doesn't have a `simperiumKey`. Some things to check:

1. Does your entity inherit from a parent entity in your model file (usually SPManagedObject) that has the `simperiumKey` attribute of type String?
2. Is the class for your entity set to `SPManagedObject`? Or, if you're using a custom subclass, have you updated the header file for your subclass to inherit from `SPManagedObject` instead of `NSManagedObject`?
3. If you're manually adding the `simperiumKey` attribute to a model (for example, to micromanage your tables: [Inherit from SPManagedObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565002/inherit-from-spmanagedobject)), you may also need to manually add the `simperiumKey` and `ghostData` variables to your custom subclass if you have one.

We'll also improve the log message to give you a better indication of what is happening in this case.