# Simperium doesn't tell "Simperium managing x MyEntity object instances"

Tags: simperium

In SimpleTodo, Simperium says

```
Simperium starting... 
Simperium loaded 1 entity definitions
Simperium managing 2 Todo object instances
Simperium found an existing auth token for myemail@myhost.de
Simperium starting network managers...
```

after init and start.

When starting Simperium in my own app the line saying `Simperium managing x MyEntity object instances`is missing. It says `Simperium loaded 15 entity definitions`, though.

The datamodel of my app is quite complex (hence the 15 entities) and I didn't introduce a `SPManagedObject` in my datamodel. But I changed all `NSManagedObject` superclasses to `SPManagedObject` and added the two attributes `ghostData` and `simperiumKey` to all entities.

What can I do to check if all is good? What do I have to do, to make it manage my entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We pushed a fix for Entity names tonight that should help with the problem you're having. It should now be possible to specify the `ghostData` and `simperiumKey` attributes manually if you prefer complete control over your table structure (as discussed in [Inherit from SPManagedObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565002/inherit-from-spmanagedobject)).