# Abstract entities and inheritance in Core Data

Tags: xcode, core-data, abstract-class, nsmanagedobject

I have a data model for Formula 1 races with 3 entities:

- RacingActor: Abstract entity
- Pilot: inherits from RacingActor
- Team: inherits from RacingActor

[image]

If I generate `NSManagedObject` subclasses to represent these entities, the code generated doesn't represent at all this design:

- Everything inherits from `NSManagedObject`
- Nothing prevents me from instantiating RacingActor
- The team property in Pilot is of type `NSManagedObject` instead of Team

Is this the expected behaviour? Am I supposed to fix the code generated by Xcode? Am I missing something?

BTW, I'm using Xcode 4.3.3

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6920736/832111) answer makes me believe that entity inheritance/ abstract entities is not the right choice for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Core Data at the core is an object relational mapping library. Long time ago it was called Entreprise Object Framework, part of WebObjects.

So yes, the base object for any persistant object managed by Core Data is `NSManagedObject`, and you can do whatever you want with them.

In your example, Team and Pilot will share a common table, and you'll be able to use queries to retrieve Teams and Pilots at once. That's the idea.

The Objective-C inheritance tree (if you use custom classes) can mirror the model you defined, but it doesn't need to. You can create a custom `RacingActor` class, use it as a base class for custom `Team` and `Pilot` classes, or you can tell the model to use `RacingActor` for `Team` and `Pilot` objects. You can even define a completely unrelated base class (provided `NSManagedObject` is a parent, directly or indirectly) for `Team` and / or `Pilot` if you want to.

You are then free to implement the specific behaviors you need in your business logic, either in controllers or in custom data classes.

Comment: I would suggest against doing inheritance in core data unless your data set is very small. Performance degrades very quickly with inheritance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276369/prevent-core-data-from-combining-entities-into-one-table?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917494/core-data-performance-with-single-parent-entity?lq=1.