# Use my subclass of NSManagedObject as superclass for CoreData Entities

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Is it posible to configure superclass for CoreData Entities subclassing? I want to change NSManagedObject to my subclass of NSManagedObject.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can, you can set an entity to be abstract in core data and then define subclasses of it. Will try to find docs. Try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385306/abstract-entities-and-inheritance-in-core-data

Comment: No, I mean following: 1. Subclass NSManagedObject 2. Configure CoreData for using my subclass for all objects and superclass when I create specific classes for entities

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: In my app I have a lot of business entities, but these entities are dictionaries, sales, appointments and so on, and every this kind has own base logic, that wy I want to implement it inside superclass

Comment: You can use whatever subclass of NSManagedObject you want to. Just type it into the entity definition. You can't set it once and have it always happen, though; you have to do it for each and every entity.

Comment: It's may not a good idea to setup an abstract entity in NSManagedObjectModel, and then link all entities as a subclass of it. Because core data will map all these sub-entities into one table, and may cause performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `NSManagedObject` and set it as the class e.g. `MyManagedObject` in the image below but you will still have to set this for all the entities in your `datamodel`. There is no way to set your own managed object class which can be used for all entities by default it can only be NSManagedObject.

[image]